# Can dot net nuke skins be created without using any graphics editing program?

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning, dotnetnuke-6

I'm looking at creating my own dnn skin.  All the articles that I can find talk alot about using photoshop to create an image and slicing and blah, blah, blah.  I want to know if I can create a new skin by only modifying an existing ascx file and creating a custom stylesheet.  I don't see how photoshop gets involved unless you just have to have rounded corners and everything using gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can certainly create DNN skins without getting a graphic editing application involved. Apparently someone needs to write some better DNN skinning articles. The DNN skinning architecture is pretty much unlimited, you can do anything you can do with ASP.NET (except for Master Pages but between skins and containers you get the same capabilities).

Joe Brinkman (one of DNN's founders) started (but never finished) a nice series on creating DNN skins with nary a mention of Dreamweaver. It's a good place to get started though he does start with an HTML skin rather than going straight to ASCX(my preference).

http://www.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2010/06/28/DotNetNuke-Skinning-101-%28Part-1%29.aspx

Comment: Okay. I just want a simple clean site like stackoverflow.  Most articles for DNN skinning are really outdated.  A lot of the ones I found were circa 2008 and mention using Dreamweaver....*groan*

Comment: Part of that might be DNN skinning hasn't really changed much at all since the beginning, which shows how solid of an architecture it is, but I guess most people figure it's all been covered. The main thing that has changed is the menu-ing system. In the old days, it was Solpart, then DNN Menu, and now the DDR Menu. Certainly skinning updates need to cover proper use of the latest menus... I'll try to get to it sometime soon.